# Background a TabHost on Android

Tags: android, background, android-tabhost

I have created a `TabHost` in main activity with 4 tab specs. I have set the background for the Tab host (drawable, png image) and made all activities in the tab specs to be transparent.

For example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <!-- Dummy item to prevent EditText from receiving focus -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="0px"/>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/etContactSearch" 
        android:layout_height="60dip" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/search_contact" >

    </EditText>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/lvContacts" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_margin="1dp"  
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
        android:listSelector="@drawable/relative_layout_clickable">

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And one of the tab specs has some linear layouts and list activity:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/bck_list">

   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:padding="0dp">

       <TabWidget
           android:id="@android:id/tabs"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
           android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:padding="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

When I start the application from Eclipse, the first time it runs, the background (`@drawable/bck_list`) is shown perfectly. But if I close the application and run it again, the background is missing (black color is showing instead).

What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost
                .newTabSpec("tab_1")
                .setIndicator(g(R.string.TList))
                .setIndicator(g(R.string.TList),
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lis))
                .setContent(new Intent().setClass(this, GList.class)));
```